# How to add List of SongInfo from Flutter Audio Query to audio service MediaItem in flutter?

Tags: flutter, just-audio, flutter-audio-query

I tried to look for solutions on internet but I didn't get one. I also tried some ways but still it didn't work. I have used just audio and flutter audio query plugins for audio player, and I tried to use audio service plugin for making it running in background and notification controls. I don't know how to implement the `List<SongInfo`> to .`<MediaItem>`

Sample code for Audio Query

```
List<SongInfo> songs = [];

void getTracks() async {
    songs = await audioQuery.getSongs();
    setState(() {
      songs = songs;
    });
  }
```

Sample for audio Service:

```
class AudioPlayer extends BackgroundAudioTask{
  final FlutterAudioQuery audioQuery = FlutterAudioQuery();

  //background audio player class
  final _queue = <MediaItem>[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`List.map` is perfect for converting a list of one type to a list of another type.

```dart
_queue.addAll(songs.map((song) => MediaItem(
      id: song.id,
      album: song.album,
      title: song.title,
    )));
```

This maps each song into a media item by taking each property value of the song and using it as the appropriate parameter value when constructing the media item. `map` will do this for each song in the list and produce an iterable of media items which you can either add to your `_queue` as demonstrated above, or alternatively converted to a list with `.toList()`.